# OpenMPI specify executable for specific nodes

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, openmpi

I have a heterogeneous computing cluster that I would like to run parallel computing tasks on using OpenMPI. Since not all nodes in the cluster can run the same executable (by virtue of being heterogeneous) I would like for some of the nodes to compile their own version of the program and have Open MPI invoke that executable on those nodes. My first question is whether OpenMPI enables this kind of computing across heterogeneous architectures.

If so, my second question is how to specify which executables to run on which nodes. For example lets say `node0`, `node1`, and `node2` can run executable `prog1` and `node3`, `node4`, and `node5` can run executable `prog2`, where `prog1` and `prog2` are the same program but compiled for different architectures using the `mpicc` or `mpic++` wrapper compilers.

If I wanted to run this program in parallel across all nodes would I do the following:

`mpirun -n 3 --hosts node0,node1,node2 prog1 : -n 3 --hosts node3,node4,node5 prog2`

If not, what would I do to achieve this effect? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006325/heterogeneous-nodes-in-openmpi?rq=1) post indicates that heterogeneous cluster computing is supported by OpenMPI but I must build OpenMPI with the `--enable-heterogeneous` flag. I'm not sure how to do this since my cluster is running ArchLinux and I installed OpenMPI with `pacman`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note there is a typo (`--host` does not require an ending `s`), so your command should be

```
mpirun -n 3 --host node0,node1,node2 prog1 : -n 3 --host node3,node4,node5 prog2
```

`--enable-heterogeneous` is needed so Open MPI can be ran on heterogeneous systems (for example between Intel x86_64 (little endian) and a sparcv9 (big endian) nodes). If OpenMPI (coming with ArchLinux) was not configured with this flag, then you should rebuild this package. an other option is to rebuild Open MPI and install it into an alternate directory.

Last but not least, heterogeneous support is (very) lightly tested, and i strongly encourage you to use the latest Open MPI 3.0 series.

Comment: Great. So once I have OpenMPI built with that flag, I can go ahead and compile my separate executables and execute them with that command?

Comment: i think so, what kind of architectures do you plan to run on ?

Comment: Some nodes in the cluster have x86 chipsets and some are ARM (admittedly a poor-man's cluster, more of an educational project kind of thing)

Comment: ok, so there is no need to convert between small and big endian and that will make things easier ! note Open MPI should be installed in the same location on all your systems.

Comment: I tried getting this to work and did not have success. After being able to spin up processes on all x86 processors with `mpirun`, I tried to spin up a process for an ARM compiled executable from an x86 node and was unable. I received an `ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.`

Comment: i suggest we continue the troubleshooting either on the Open MPI User mailing list or on [github](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues). in any case, please provide the `configure` command lines on both x86_64 and ARM

Comment: Actually, I just got it! I had a problem with conflicting installations of OpenMPI but after clearing that up I actually got it to work with the syntax we discussed. Thanks!